# PowerPoint custom slides

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I wonder if someone could help me; I've created a very large PowerPoint (2016) which different sections and I'm currently using a custom drop down menu to navigate around the slides but I'm wondering if there is a way I could (from first slide) select multiple slides (let's say 1, 3, 8, 16, 20) and then press go. Then only those slides would be shown.

Not sure if this is possible, if it is could you point me in the right direction on how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use powerpoint too often, so apologies if this isn't any help.

```
Dim iCount As Integer

Public Sub Load()
ListBox1.Clear
ListBox1.MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectMulti

For iCount = 1 To ActivePresentation.Slides(ActivePresentation.Slides.Count).SlideNumber
    ListBox1.AddItem iCount
Next iCount

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

For iCount = 1 To ActivePresentation.Slides(ActivePresentation.Slides.Count).SlideNumber
    ActivePresentation.Slides(iCount).SlideShowTransition.Hidden = msoFalse
Next iCount

For iCount = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    If ListBox1.Selected(iCount) Then ActivePresentation.Slides(iCount + 1).SlideShowTransition.Hidden = msoCTrue
Next iCount
End Sub
```

I created a listbox and button on the first slide (added via the development tab). All slide numbers are added  to this listbox when the sub "Load" is ran, then when the button is clicked all selected slides are made visible, all others made hidden. This can be flipped if required. Let me know if you need any assistance, i'm happy to make any changes.

Comment: Thank you, tried it but no luck, it's probably me not doing something right. Could you send me a PPt so I can have a look or do you want me to send you what I've done?

Comment: I created a ListBox and Button on the first slide and didn't rename either object. I then opened the VBA Editor and navigated to the first slide, I added the code above and clicked into the "Load" sub and pressed F5 to run it. This should populate the list box with all slide numbers within the powerpoint. You should then be able to close the VBA Editor and use the ListBox on slide one to select the slides you want to hide and when you click the button those slides should be hidden.

Feel free to send me a link to a file and I can add the code in there for you so you can figure it out.

Comment: Working great, thank you. Would you know how I can change the numbers to the name of the slide?

My slides have names such as, Welcome, Quiz, About etc.

Comment: Sure, should be pretty simple. Try changing `ListBox1.AddItem iCount` to `ListBox1.AddItem ActivePresentation.Slides(iCount).Name`

Comment: No problem, let me know if you need anything else. Also, could you please mark the answer above as useful/answered? 

Thanks.